# How to mask/encrypt MongoDB data?

Tags: mongodb, encryption, mongodb-query

We have a MongoDB database and we would like to mask or encrypt (I don't know which feature should be enough here) some fields from some collections "permanently".

Example:

We have a collection called `users`, in this collecion we would like to mask data from fields: `nr_cnpj`, `ds_email`, `nm_user` (suppose data below is real):

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64f515cc716f37361f7f19b3"
  },
  "dt_birth": {
    "$date": "1992-12-25T02:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "ds_email": "user@hotmail.com",
  "ds_gender": 0,
  "ds_password": "adas8d1as6d1as6d81asda",
  "ic_emailverified": true,
  "ds_cnpj": "123456/0001",
  "nm_user": "Test User"
}
```

To this (random values for given fields):

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64f515cc716f37361f7f19b3"
  },
  "dt_birth": {
    "$date": "1992-12-25T02:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "ds_email": "test@test.com",
  "ds_gender": 0,
  "ds_password": "adas8d1as6d1as6d81asda",
  "ic_emailverified": true,
  "ds_cnpj": "987654/0001",
  "nm_user": "John Doe"
}
```

So that, sometimes I’ll need production data to help develop new features or
build tests to replicate user behavior. In order to re-create production scenarios in
a local development environment, you may need to get the actual data — but without exposing that information publicly to developers mostly.

I wouldn't like to create `views` in this case, only keep collections and fake data so that whenever someone query that data, it will be with fake already.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://github.com/rueckstiess/mgeneratejs and its successor https://github.com/feliixx/mgodatagen. Don't compromise on "masking"  data that you consider sensitive - "mask" everything. Both tools generate totally safe random data, and all you need to share with developers is the generator rules which define shape of your data.

Comment: @AlexBlex So, in case we have 100k documents inside that collection. Is it possible for me to "mask" those, before passing it to the developer? Or this tool only gerenates fake data instead of "masking" existing documents?

Comment: MongoDB enterprise supports Client-Side Field-Level encryption (CSFLE) - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/csfle/ .   If using MongoDB Enterprise 7.0 or later you can use Queryable Encryption - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/queryable-encryption/.  In either case, you can use explicit encryption if using the community edition.

Comment: @GuilhermeMatheus the latter - you share only "shape" of the documents, and developers will generate as many as they want